# Encountering NullInjectorError in Angular 5 while testing a component that works with injectors directly to get the value of a variable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular and I am testing an Angular component which works with injectors directly to get desired values. Now I am having a hard time as to how to pass those values while testing.

Here is my component.ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injector, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss'],
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  isShared: boolean;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { 
    this.isShared = this.injector.get('isShared');
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Here is my component.spec.ts code:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

describe('UserComponent', () => {
  let component: UserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ UserComponent ],
      providers: []
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Here is the error message I get when I try any of the above-mentioned solutions.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[isShared]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[isShared]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for isShared!
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx1zw.png)

Comment: Don't understand why you need to provide Injector directly. Is "isShared" a service? Because, Injector can only create an instance using get method for the classes that have @Injectable() annotation and are added into the Providers.

Comment: Hey Akshay, I just cleaned the question a little bit so that it is easier to interpret...I am working on someone else's code that I can't change and they used injectors directly...isShared is a variable that is taking its value from some other component via a service...this is a miniature of the scenario that I posted here as I am not allowed to post their source code. Please help me in sending isShared's value in the testing environment...

Comment: Try adding the following to the providers in spec file:

{provide: isShared, useValue: true/false}

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add : `{provide: isShared, useValue: true/false}` in your providers of TestingMudule.

As the compiler is not able to find the provider for isShared in Testing Environment.